# Firebase CLI - Which project id takes precedence when deploying?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

I have a single codebase which I have deploying out to 2 firebase projects, `dev` and `prod`.

My `.firebaserc` contains:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "dev"
  }
}
```

However, if i type `firebase list`, i see

```
┌─────────────────────┬───────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ Name                │ Project ID / Instance │ Permissions │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ dev                 │ dev                   │ Owner       │
├─────────────────────┼───────────────────────┼─────────────┤
│ prod (current)      │ prod                  │ Owner       │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

I see this is due to the actual project id being stored in `~/.config/configstore/firebase-tools.json`:

```
 "activeProjects": {
      "/mnt/d/testfb": "prod"
  }
```

I'd like to know the order of precedence in determining the firebase project id to use. I looked at the firebase cli github, but unfortunately I got a bit lost trying to follow the files around.

Is it safe to assume that the `firebase-tools.json` is the point of truth? If so, what is the purpose of the `.firebaserc` file?

Answer (score 0):

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/

> A `.firebaserc` file that stores your project aliases.

a `.firebaserc` file is Only alias settings.

> When you select a Firebase project during project initialization, the project's alias is automatically called default. However, to allow project-specific commands to run against a different Firebase project but use the same project directory, run the following command from within your project directory.
>
> `firebase use alias_or_projectID` Switch between aliases for your project directory
>
> If you have a development project that's for your use only, you can either pass the `--project` flag with each command or run firebase use projectID without defining the Firebase project an alias.

In case of to set the following code to a `.firebaserc`.

```
{
  "projects": {
    "dev": "<dev-project-id>",
    "prod": "<prod-project-id>"
  }
}
```

You can change the current Firebase project using alias not project id. Like this.

- `firebase use dev`
- `firebase use prod`

If you run `firebase` command whitout the `--project` flag then `firebase` command will run against the current Firebase project.